# Swift pod in objective-C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, ios-charts

my pod looks like this

```
platform :ios, '8.1'

pod 'Masonry'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'SSKeychain'
pod 'Reachability'
```

When I add 'pod Charts', I get error like this

```
[!] Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; this feature is still in beta. Add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile or target to opt into using it. The Swift Pod being used is: Charts
```

If I update podfile to this:

```
platform :ios, '8.1'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Masonry'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'SSKeychain'
pod 'Reachability'
pod 'Charts'
```

It messes up project and SSKeychain shows nonsense errors like duplicate interface and enums definitions.

Should I do something more to support Swift pod framework? Or I have to update project to remove somehow those open source files (SSKeychain and so on)?

Comment: maybe you should ask it on github and provide some error messages

Comment: I just ended up using other library - JBChartView

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should remove the cache for a given pod, or clear the cache completely. Please do it according to [pod cache clean](https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_cache_clean)

> `pod cache clean [NAME]`
>
> Remove the cache for a given pod, or clear the
>   cache completely.
>
> If there is multiple cache for various versions of the requested pod,
>   you will be asked which one to clean. Use `--all` to clean them all.
>
> If you dont give a podNAME, you need to specify the `--all` flag (this
>   is to avoid cleaning all the cache by mistake).
>
> ### Options:
>
> #### --all
>
> Remove all the cached pods without asking.
>
> ### Inherited options:
>
> #### --silent
>
> Show nothing.
>
> #### --verbose
>
> Show more debugging information.
>
> #### --no-ansi
>
> Show output without ANSI codes.
>
> #### --help
>
> Show help banner of specified command.

Hope it helps to you.

Comment: please summarize the link